# Qt 5.3.2 Alphabuffer with Quick 2 windows distortion

Tags: qt, opengl, alpha-transparency, qt5.3

In any project I try to use alpha transparency with-in the window always ends up looking distorted and all colors messed up I always end up with what looks like a sharpen filter effect on all elements of the window while QQuickWindow::setDefaultAlphaBuffer(true); if I set it true that's when it happens however when set to false everything looks fine!

This even effects the standard examples included with Qt 5.3 SDK

Im using the Opengl build 64bit version of QT...

My GPU is Nvidia Geforce GTX 750 TI latest driver installed...

Any Idea what is going wrong here? is there a better way to set transparency for Window?

Comment: If you create a minimal test case that reproduces the issue, you should probably submit a bug report and edit your question to include the link to the bug report.